# concurrent.futures captures all exceptions

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, concurrent.futures

I have coded myself into an interesting situation that I don't know how to get out of.

I have a number of functions I am running in a number of parallel threads, but when an exception is thrown within one of the threads the code continues on with no notification

```py
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # queue up the threads for parallel execution
        futureHost.update({executor.submit(infoCatalina, host): host for host in onlineHosts})
        futureHost.update({executor.submit(infoVersion, host): host for host in onlineHosts})
        futureHost.update({executor.submit(infoMount, host): host for host in onlineHosts})
        # go through the threads as they complete
        for _ in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futureHost):
            x = progress(x, progBarLength)
```

If I put `1/0` to throw a ZeroDivisionError before or after the infoVersion line the correct error is thrown.

```py
        1/0   # will throw an error
        futureHost.update({executor.submit(infoVersion, host): host for host in onlineHosts})
        1/0   # will throw an error
```

However, if I put `1/0` within `infoVersion()` I get no message when the error is thrown and the function exits.

```py
def infoVersion(host):
    print('This statement prints')
    1/0      # does not throw an error
    print('This statement does not print')
```

I have to put messages as above to find out where my code is dying.

How can I get errors to show up in my code again?

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are captured by the future object:

```python
       for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futureHost):
           if future.exception() is not None:
               print(f'ERROR: {future}: {future.exception()}')
               continue
```